git push --set-upstream to GitHub not creating repository as expected
I am having trouble pushing a new local repository to Github over SSH.
What I do is:

Initialize a new local repository and create an initial commit
Use git push --set-upstream git@github.com:USERNAME/test.git main

At this point, I expect to have a new remote repository created on Github, and have origin for the local repository point to the remote URL for fetch and push.
This expectation is based on previous experience with GitLab, where this works just fine. Despite extensive research, I had not come across any documentation indicating that this is not supported in Github.
I get an error message:
ERROR: repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists

Also, remote -v returns nothing. No remote or origin were set.
To troubleshoot, I have tried this.
Validate SSH authentication with ssh -T git@github.com. This returns "Hi USERNAME! You've successfully authenticated,..."
I have also created a new repository on Github through the web UI, then used SSH to clone the repository locally. I edited, created a new commit and was able to successfully push changes back to Github via SSH.
So SSH authentication appears to work, along with git clone and git push.
Using git remote add origin git@github.com:USERNAME/test.git does add the origin URLs for fetch and push, but then `git push --set-upstream origin main' fails with the same "repository not found" error as above.
It seems the issue is that I cannot set an upstream branch, and/or Github does not let me create a new repository over SSH.

Github does not create new repositories over HTTPS or SSH. To push you need have a repository already created. You can create a new repository beforehand with web UI or API. PS. The downvote isn't mine.

"At this point, I expect to have a new remote repository created on Github" Stop expecting that. Git push does not create a remote repo. In fact, no local Git command can create a remote repo. For GitHub, you can use the gh command line tool to create the remote repo before pushing with Git. https://cli.github.com/

@matt GitLab can create repositories with git push but no other hostings AFAIK.

@phd That's a salutary point, because it suggests that the OP's idea that git push might create the remote for you is not silly!

@matt It's not silly, just not implemented. GitHub doesn't do that but has an API and many command-line wrappers for the API, gh, hub, etc.

As mentioned in the comments (thanks to matt, phd), this is possible with GitLab but not with github. The OP understandably but wrongly expected feature parity :).
